# How to make a GET request to Rails API that returns a random record via Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written a working method to return a random record within the console.

```js
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  ... 
  
  def self.random
   Model.limit(1).order("RANDOM()")
  end
end
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to use this method to have the Rails API return that record.

Possibly add a conditional to the *show()* function in the associated controller? ...

```js
def show
  if Model.find(params[:id])
    @item = Model.find(params[:id])
  else
    @item = Model.random
  end
 end
```

As you can probably tell, I'm a bit lost. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in your model. Or, you might try in your controller:

```
def show
  render json: Model.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Model.all.sample
end
```

`Model.find(params[:id])` will throw an error if the record is not found and you'll never reach your else statement.

`Model.find_by(id: params[:id])` will return `nil` if the record isn't found, in which case the `or` clause will return a random record.

Then you use `render json:` to return the record in its JSON format.

I suppose this assumes you've done something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    ...
  end
end
```

In `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  `Model.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first` in the Model and `@item = Model.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Model.random` in the show method in the Controller and it is working.